# Made change to my account's .bashrc and can't login but also cannot login with any other account

Tags: bashrc

I had an issue with running scp on a workstation and followed the advice in this link to resolve it:

https://www.fir3net.com/UNIX/General/why-does-scp-file-transfer-fail-but-there-is-no-error.html

which was to add `[[ $- == *i* ]] || return` to the top of .bashrc. After doing this, launching Putty prompts for the login and password, then it shuts down. So I understand that adding that command messed up my .bashrc, but I can't login with another account either which makes no sense.

I have a colleague with direct access to this workstation who can login and make changes. I had him delete the offending command line and reboot, but it behaves the same way, as though all .bashrc files are affected, which is not the case.

Any light you can shed on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The default ~/.bashrc (copied from /etc/skel on account creation) contains an equivalent statement (using a `case... esac` construct) - it's hard to see how this would break any logins. Are you sure there was not another change made to the system at around the same time? Have you tried logging in with an alternate shell such as `/bin/sh` (or with `/bin/bash --norc`)?

Comment: There might be more than one `.bashrc` file. What is the path to the one you changed and check with your colleague for the path of the one they changed.

Comment: The change to my .bashrc file is the only change I made. I tried to ssh with "bin/sh" and "/bin/bash --norc" as advised, but they all behave the same way. Note, each time I ssh in, it appears to actually login, it displays "Welcome to Ubuntu... " then "Last login: ..." then "Connection to (ip_addr) closed."   I also tried to scp the contents of /etc/skel/ from another workstation to the home dir to overwrite the files, but that had no effect (but it did not return an error).